# sys.sp_cdc_stop_job not on server

Tags: azure-sql-database, change-data-capture

How to restart capture job (for Change Data Capture), if I don't have this procedure - sys.sp_cdc_stop_job on the server?
(using Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8 Sep 18 2021 19:01:34 Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation )
Need to restart it to reflect my changes in configuration by sp_cdc_change_job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Azure SQL Database the **capture and cleanup** SQL Server Agent **jobs** are **replaced by** a change data capture **scheduler** that periodically invokes stored procedures to capture and cleanup of the change tables. This scheduler runs stored procedures automatically.

You can check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/administer-and-monitor-change-data-capture-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) to understand how the **Capture job** initiates the running of stored procedures.